# Spring Boot, transactions

Tags: spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

- Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7
- Hibernate
- MS SQL DB

I have some problems with understanding transactions in Spring Boot. I have a web controller that save files locally and updates a row in one table in my DB. The problem is that if there are multiple files uploaded the same row will be updated in the DB. I was hoping to use optimistic locking to fix this problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class Metadata{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @Version
    private int version;
}
```

In my controller i call the add method in my RetryService to update the DB:

```
@Service
public class RetryService {

    @Autowired
    private MetadataRepository metadataRepository;

    public Metadata add(final long dbId, final FileMetadata file) {
        int i = 0;

        do {
            try {
                Metadata md = doTransaction(dbId, file);
                return md;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                sleep(i);
            }
        }
        while(++i < retries);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Metadata doTransaction(final long dbId, final FileMetadata file) {
        Metadata metadata = metadataRepository.findById(dbId).get();
        metadata.addFile(file);
        metadataRepository.save(metadata);

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

If I then try to upload for example 100 files 10 threads will start to save to the DB. For most of the updates all goes well. Some of the threads do on or to retry before they successfully updates the DB. But then for some threads I get this exception:

```
11:42:44.904 [http-nio-8094-exec-2] [host=127.0.0.1, uri=/api/v1/files/4ae87fa6-c672-45a4-a992-ae37476d5aeb, user=anonymousUser] ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]
11:42:44.911 [http-nio-8094-exec-2] [host=127.0.0.1, uri=/api/v1/files/4ae87fa6-c672-45a4-a992-ae37476d5aeb, user=anonymousUser] ERROR o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:301)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)

    ...

11:42:44.917 [http-nio-8094-exec-2] [host=127.0.0.1, uri=/api/v1/files/4ae87fa6-c672-45a4-a992-ae37476d5aeb, user=anonymousUser] WARN  n.p.m.lagring.rest.RetryService - Error updating medieobject, retry 1 of 20  Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
```

I think that the most important parts of the exceptions are:

- Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
- Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1;
- Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection

After this exception I see that the thread retries, but will always fail.

So my question is why does this work for most of the uploads, even if the threads have to retry, but then for a few threads this fails.

Comment: Your `@Transactional` is actually pretty much useless. Spring uses AOP to apply transactions and AOP will only work for method calls INTO the method it will not work for internal method calls. Hence your `@Transactional` is pretty much useless and it will only invalidate the outer transaction, which is why it will keep failing. . Also you hoped to solve the problem what isn't solved? You get an exception if multiple threads update the same entity at the same time, that is the whole point of optimistic locking.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get an exception when the optimistick lock fail, but then I want to retry X number of times until it succesfully updates the DB.
Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Comment: The problem is that your `@Transactional` isn't doing anything (as stated by my first comment). Only the outer transaction wil be invalidated. If you want a new transaction the `doTransaction` needs to be in another class or you need to use a `TransactionTemplate` and manually control the new transaction.

Comment: Ok, thanks I now understand. I will try to have it in another class first.